# Python Import Errors: No module named <myPackage>

Tags: python, import, package, pytest

I know this should be easy and I know that other people online have asked this question, but I feel like I understand all of their answers and the concepts, yet my import is still throwing errors.

I have this directory structure

```
root/myPackage/
root/tests/test_1.py
```

in test_1.py I have:

```
import myPackage
...
```

I am running on the command line from the root:

```
$ pytest tests OR python tests/test_1.py
```

...just anything to get this script to run really. I've used pytest and have run python scripts before

and I keep getting the

```
No module named 'myPackage' error
```

I thought if I run the test from the root I would still be able to access myPackage... this is really contradicting my previous understanding and the internet... send help if you know why I'm getting importing errors.

ALSO, when I take the test_1.py out of the tests directory and run it from the root it works without errors. So this structure works

```
root/myPackage/
root/test_1.py
```

Comment: Is this Python 2?  If so, `myPackage/__init__.py` must exist.

Comment: @JohnGordon it's python3 and it myPackage/__init__.py exists

Comment: How about `root/tests/__init__.py`?

Comment: @Beethoven's7th why would tests need an init. It's just a folder. I eventually want to just be able to call pytest tests from the root

Comment: @JoshuaSegal if pytest is trying to discover and run your tests, it will be reading the test folder like it's a package which would require the init file.

Comment: I don't think being discovered is the issue. The tests are being found and run, but with import errors... Also, I've played around with them and tried python tests/test_1.py and I put a main function there and everything. Same import error. Also, by default pytest searches for test_*.py

Comment: Would you be able to share the contents of your setup.py file? (and setup.cfg if exists)

Comment: I don't have a setup.py just a requirements.txt that's in the root. Do you want to see that? Or maybe not having the setup.py is the issue?

Comment: I think the setup.py makes the package available in my environment or something. The package not in my environment is the problem I think.

Comment: No problem. Can you share the full directory structure you have for your project?

Comment: The full directory structure is actually quite long and making a setup.py like this worked!
from setuptools import setup
```
setup(
    name='BlueSlide',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=['BlueSlide'],
    include_package_data=True,
)
```
do you know if there are other ways to install your own package instead of using setup.py. I don't really know too much about them, but I feel like there should be a simpler way to install my own package into my python virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreating your project from the information provided, I was able to reproduce your error and fixed it by including an `__init__.py` file under the tests directory.

Here's my project structure:

## root/myPackage

- `__init__.py`
- module.py

## root/tests

- `__init__.py`
- test_1.py

That should allow you to run `pytest tests` successfully.

Comment: I'm confused on why this works. What does putting an \__init\__.py in the tests folder do exactly? Tests isn't a package, so why put the \__init\__.py?

Comment: Without the init file, pytest just thinks your test file is a script and it will run it in isolation. In that context, it isn't really relevant that myPackage and tests share the root directory because pytest doesn't know it exists inside a package. Including the setup.py and using setuptools to register your package with your python environment made it possible to import your package from anywhere regardless of directory context.